# Assigning a struct pointer value from struct vector

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


struct Sn {
    int SnId;
    double spentEnergy;
};   

class Node {
    //other stuff
    private:
    vector<Sn> SnRecord;

    public:
    int getBestSn(Sn* bestSn);
    void someFunction();

};

int main()
{
   Node nd;
   nd.someFunction();
   return 0;
}
void Node::someFunction() {

    //adding some records in vector just for testing purpose
    Sn temp;
    temp.SnId = 1; temp.spentEnergy = 5;
    SnRecord.push_back(temp);

    temp.SnId = 2; temp.spentEnergy = 10;
    SnRecord.push_back(temp);

    temp.SnId = 2; temp.spentEnergy = 10;
    SnRecord.push_back(temp);
    cout << "Size of SnReocord is " << SnRecord.size() << endl;

    //choosing best sn
    Sn *bestSn;

    int returnCode = -1;
    returnCode = getBestSn(bestSn);
    if (returnCode == 0){ //means there is a best SN
        cout<< "Found best SN with id = "<< bestSn->SnId << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout <<"NO SN "<< endl;
    }
}

int Node::getBestSn(Sn* bestSn) {
    int tblSize = (int)SnRecord.size();
    if (tblSize == 0)
        return -1;
//here i have to assign *bestSn a selected value from vector
//suppose SnRecord[2] is best Sn 

    cout << "Best sn id is " << SnRecord[2].SnId<< endl; //works OK, 
    bestSn = &SnRecord[2]; ///// giving me core dump ERROR in my own program but in this simplified version it only gives wrong value
    return 0;
}
```

The output now is:

```
 Size of SnReocord is 3                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 Best sn id is 2                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 Found best SN with id = 520004336
```

In my own program it gives me Core dump error, if I comment this line (and make proper other comments according to function call), the error is gone and simulation executes normally.

I saw examples with arrays, the work if a pointer is assigned a value in this way:

```
int numbers[5];
int * p;
p = &numbers[2]; //works OK.
```

but for vectors its not working. Or may be its problem of vector of structures, I'm unable to figure out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure there is at least 4 records in the vector?  What happens if you use `at` instead of `[]`?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: I see even more copy paste errors here. Best would be to provide a piece of code that reproduces this we can copy and paste and test our self.

Comment: Btw: are you sure your code dumps in the line where you indicated it? I can see a potential crash at a later point though.

Comment: You can use iterators. BTW, you defined `Node::getBestSn` to return `void`, it's unlikely that the logic in `someFunction` could work.

Comment: I am surprised *that* line is crashing.  Are you sure getBestSn isn't declared const?  You will need the argument to getBestSn to be `Sn* & bestSn`  (or better `const Sn* & bestSn`, or worse, the equivalents with pointers).

Comment: This code won't even compile.  We need a [mcve].  Please [edit] your question so that it is complete.

Comment: Ok all, I'll edit it properly... may be on the way learn something new :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok actually the problem is solved by using suggestion of Sn* & bestSn. But I don't understand this solution. Why can't I pass a pointer variable and it saves a pointer value in it which latter could be accessed?